# Websocket header missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, ssl, rack, faye

I'm using the 'faye' gem with Rails 3.2.13. In development I'm running faye on localhost:9292 and my app on localhost:3000. I'm able to activate pop-up windows with a curl request from the command line but I can't establish a connection from within my app. The error I'm getting in my console is:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9292/faye' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing

I am trying to define a header for faye in my application.js file:

```
$(function() {
  var faye = new Faye.Client("http://localhost:9292/faye");
  faye.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  faye.subscribe('/messages', function (data) {
  alert(data);
  });
});
```

Is this the right way to add a Header?

I found a discussion of a similar problem here: https://github.com/faye/faye/issues/222  In this case the error seemed to be related to the ssl settings not being loaded. I checked my rack gem's lib directory and found

```
def ssl?
  scheme == 'https'
end
```

This seems fine. How do I know if the settings aren't being properly loaded?

Any clues about where to look next would be much appreciated.

Comment: Was this from following a railscast? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same issue while following Ryan Bates's railscast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

The Faye web socket server requires an adapter to run on Thin web server and send the upgrade header.

Adding this line to your Faye rackup file (`.ru`) will load the adapter via rack middleware:

`Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')`

I found this solution here:
https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/issues/39#issuecomment-4225647