# How can I push to Faye Server from Rails Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eventmachine, faye

I have this code:

```
def create
    message = Message.new(text: params[:message][:text], author: params[:message][:author])
    if message.save
      render json: {result: 'success'}
    else
      render json: {result: 'failure'}
    end
  end
```

I have client subscribed to Faye Server:

```
var subscription = client.subscribe('/foo', function (message) {
    getMessages();
});
```

I want to publish some message to Faye when a message is created. As listed in Faye Ruby Sever documentation, I have to do like this:

```
require 'eventmachine'

EM.run {
  client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:9292/faye')

  client.subscribe('/foo') do |message|
    puts message.inspect
  end

  client.publish('/foo', 'text' => 'Hello world')
}
```

But when I paste this code into my `create` method, it blocks the rails thread with EventMachine and server doesn't work any more.

When I use `client.publish` without `EventMachine`, I get an error.

How can I publish to Faye from server? I know that there are gems like `faye-rails` or `private_pub`, but I want to figure out how to do it myself. Is there any way to integrate EventMachine and Rails? Maybe I should run EventMachine on a different thread?

Comment: `I get an error` - whats the error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did't use Event Machine but I use **Fay-web Socket** in rails , I am using **thin web-server** for my application to show notification.

**First you add this line into you** **Gemfile**

```
gem 'faye'
gem 'thin'
```

> Now ! run bundle install   command for install gem and it's
>   dependency.
>
> Create a **faye.ru** file and add given line (a rackup file for run
>   Faye server ).

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'thin'
require 'faye'
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
run faye_server
```

> Now add line to your **application.erb** file

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', "http://localhost:9292/faye.js", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

> Create a method with name broadcast or any name which is
>   suitable for you in `websoket.rb` (first create websoket.rb file
>   inside `config/initializers` ) .

```
module Websocket
  def broadcast(channel, msg)
    message = {:channel => channel, :data => msg}
    uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:9292/faye")
    Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)
  end
end
```

> **Now use this method inside your model or controller where you want.**

**In my case I am using this inside the **Notification.rb** to sending notification.**

**Example**

```
after_create :send_notificaton 

def send_notification
    broadcast("/users/#{user.id}", {username: "#{user.full_name }", msg: "Hello you are invited for project--| #{project.name} | please check your mail"})
end
```

**For subscriber**

```
<div id="websocket" style="background-color: #999999;">
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
var faye = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
        faye.subscribe('/users/<%= current_user.id %>', function (data) {
            $('#websocket').text(data.username + ": " + data.msg);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Now ! Run your faye.ru file using terminal**

```
rackup faye.ru -s thin -E prodcution
```

**For details** 
[Faye websocket](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html)

Comment: I am calling this in main thread .. Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)

Comment: Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin') is missing faye.ru file on Anil Yadav's answer. I had this error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286228/websocket-header-missing/19419313#19419313

Comment: This is far from ideal. The `HTTP.post_form` will hang until timeout...which can be a long time