# Where to start, implement long-polling in Faye for iOS

Tags: ios, long-polling, faye

I'm using `MZFayeClient` (https://github.com/m1entus/MZFayeClient) using built in `WebSocket`.
I need to implement long-polling technique.
How to do it? Where to start?
There isn't information (or enough information) on how to do it or if there an Faye library with long-polling.

Answer (score 5):

I am **not a IOS developer** but one of my project I was helping to my IOS team for integrating the Faye server.

On my application we had a faye-server already running on rails framework for sending notification then we decide to sending notification to IOS device using same faye-server.

*IOS team just follow the instruction of*: https://github.com/pcrawfor/FayeObjC

```
self.client = [[MZFayeClient alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://198.128.0.1:9292/faye"]];

ws://198.128.0.1:9292/faye // this URL is same which is used on web-app.
```

*subscribeToChannel & other* methods are same like we are using on web-app.

> Simple Faye Setup for Rails application .

[How can I push to Faye Server from Rails Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567167/how-can-i-push-to-faye-server-from-rails-controller/33567635#33567635)

It will work for me I hope will also for you ..

*sorry for my bad english ;)*

Answer (score 2):

**1.** [**Server up and running:**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails--net-22600)

`sudo rackup faye.ru -E production -s thin` to start the Faye server

```
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth) Maximum connections set to
1024 Listening on localhost:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

Check if server is working

```
curl http://localhost:9292/faye -d 'message={"channel":"/server", "data":"hello"}'
```

Response

```
[{"channel":"/server","successful":true}]
```

Server log:

```
[Faye::RackAdapter] Received message via HTTP POST:
"{\"channel\":\"/server\", \"data\":\"hello\"}" [Faye::Server]
Processing messages: [{"channel":"/server","data":"hello"}] (local:
false) [Faye::Server] Passing through incoming extensions:
{"channel":"/server","data":"hello"} [Faye::Server] Handling message:
{"channel":"/server","data":"hello"} (local: false)
[Faye::Engine::Proxy] Publishing message
{"channel":"/server","data":"hello"} [Faye::Server] Processing reply:
{"channel":"/server","successful":true} [Faye::Server] Passing through
outgoing extensions: {"channel":"/server","successful":true}
[Faye::Server] Returning replies:
[{"channel":"/server","successful":true}] [Faye::RackAdapter] HTTP
response: "[{\"channel\":\"/server\",\"successful\":true}]"
```

**2. Work with client:**
Download [MZFayeClient](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFayeClient)

```
cd FayeObjC-master/examples
pod install
open FayeObjC.xcworkspace
```

MZViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.client = [[MZFayeClient alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:9292/faye"]];
    [self.client subscribeToChannel:@"/server" success:^{
        NSLog(@"ok");
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Server %@",error);
    } receivedMessage:^(NSDictionary *message) {
        NSLog(@"Server %@",message);
    }];

    self.client.delegate = self;
}
```

**3. Build example:**
Touch on connect:

```
[Faye::RackAdapter] Received message via WebSocket[hybi-13]:
"{\"supportedConnectionTypes\":[\"long-polling\",\"callback-polling\",\"iframe\",\"websocket\"],\"channel\":\"\\/meta\\/handshake\",\"minimumVersion\":\"1.0beta\",\"version\":\"1.0\"}"
[Faye::Server] Processing messages:
[{"supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","callback-polling","iframe","websocket"],"channel":"/meta/handshake","minimumVersion":"1.0beta","version":"1.0"}]
(local: false) [Faye::Server] Passing through incoming extensions:
{"supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","callback-polling","iframe","websocket"],"channel":"/meta/handshake","minimumVersion":"1.0beta","version":"1.0"}
[Faye::Server] Handling message:
{"supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","callback-polling","iframe","websocket"],"channel":"/meta/handshake","minimumVersion":"1.0beta","version":"1.0"}
(local: false) [Faye::Engine::Proxy] Created new client
"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5" [Faye::Engine::Proxy] Ping
"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5", 45 [Faye::Server] Processing reply:
{"channel":"/meta/handshake","successful":true,"version":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","cross-origin-long-polling","callback-polling","websocket","eventsource","in-process"],"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","advice":{"reconnect":"retry","interval":0,"timeout":45000}}
[Faye::Server] Passing through outgoing extensions:
{"channel":"/meta/handshake","successful":true,"version":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","cross-origin-long-polling","callback-polling","websocket","eventsource","in-process"],"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","advice":{"reconnect":"retry","interval":0,"timeout":45000}}
[Faye::Server] Returning replies:
[{"channel":"/meta/handshake","successful":true,"version":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","cross-origin-long-polling","callback-polling","websocket","eventsource","in-process"],"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","advice":{"reconnect":"retry","interval":0,"timeout":45000}}]
[Faye::RackAdapter] Received message via WebSocket[hybi-13]:
"{\"channel\":\"\\/meta\\/connect\",\"clientId\":\"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5\",\"connectionType\":\"websocket\"}"
[Faye::Server] Processing messages:
[{"channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","connectionType":"websocket"}]
(local: false) [Faye::Server] Passing through incoming extensions:
{"channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","connectionType":"websocket"}
[Faye::Server] Handling message:
{"channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","connectionType":"websocket"}
(local: false) [Faye::Engine::Proxy] Accepting connection from
"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5" [Faye::Engine::Proxy] Ping
"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5", 45 [Faye::RackAdapter] Received
message via WebSocket[hybi-13]:
"{\"channel\":\"\\/meta\\/subscribe\",\"clientId\":\"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5\",\"subscription\":\"\\/server\"}"
[Faye::Server] Processing messages:
[{"channel":"/meta/subscribe","clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","subscription":"/server"}]
(local: false) [Faye::Server] Passing through incoming extensions:
{"channel":"/meta/subscribe","clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","subscription":"/server"}
[Faye::Server] Handling message:
{"channel":"/meta/subscribe","clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","subscription":"/server"}
(local: false) [Faye::Engine::Proxy] Subscribed client
"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5" to channel "/server" [Faye::Server]
Processing reply:
{"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/meta/subscribe","successful":true,"subscription":"/server"}
[Faye::Server] Passing through outgoing extensions:
{"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/meta/subscribe","successful":true,"subscription":"/server"}
[Faye::Server] Returning replies:
[{"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/meta/subscribe","successful":true,"subscription":"/server"}]
```

Type "hello" then send

```
[Faye::RackAdapter] Received message via WebSocket[hybi-13]:
"{\"data\":{\"text\":\"hello\"},\"clientId\":\"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5\",\"channel\":\"\\/browser\",\"id\":\"MQ==\"}"
[Faye::Server] Processing messages:
[{"data":{"text":"hello"},"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/browser","id":"MQ=="}]
(local: false)
[Faye::Server] Passing through incoming extensions:
{"data":{"text":"hello"},"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/browser","id":"MQ=="}
[Faye::Server] Handling message:
{"data":{"text":"hello"},"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/browser","id":"MQ=="}
(local: false)
[Faye::Engine::Proxy] Publishing message
{"data":{"text":"hello"},"clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/browser","id":"MQ=="}
[Faye::Server] Processing reply:
{"id":"MQ==","clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/browser","successful":true}
[Faye::Server] Passing through outgoing extensions:
{"id":"MQ==","clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/browser","successful":true}
[Faye::Server] Returning replies:
[{"id":"MQ==","clientId":"f68nwz5foyf1brczhmutdhclhnbtth5","channel":"/browser","successful":true}]
```

Hope this help.