# Rails Faye Websocket client just to send one message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, faye

I'm trying to broadcast from my controller a message to all registered clients.
The better way I found to do this is to create a Faye client in my controller, send my message, and close it right after message is sent.

```
#my_controller.rb

EM.run {
          ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new(Rails.application.config.websocket_url)
          ws.send(JSON.dump(this_order.service_json))
          EM.stop
      }
```

Although this code partially works, it closes all my browser connections to Faye.

Faye is implemented in a middleware, like this:

```
class FayeMiddleware
    KEEPALIVE_TIME = 30 # in seconds

    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
      @clients = []
    end

    def call(env)
        if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
            # WebSockets logic goes here
            ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, nil, {ping: KEEPALIVE_TIME })
            ws.on :open do |event|
              p [:open, ws.object_id]
              @clients << ws
            end

            ws.on :close do |event|
              p [:close, ws.object_id, event.code, event.reason]
              @clients.delete(ws)
              ws = nil
            end

            ws.on :message do |event|
              p [:message, event.data]
              puts event.data
              @clients.each {|client| client.send(event.data) }
            end
            # Return async Rack response
            ws.rack_response
        else
            @app.call(env)
        end
    end
end
```

I made this code referring to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets) tutorial.

I don't understand why all my web sockets get closed when I stop my EM. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Make a module and use it this way . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567167/how-can-i-push-to-faye-server-from-rails-controller/33567635#33567635

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
EM.run {
          ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new(Rails.application.config.websocket_url)
          ws.on :open do |event|
            ws.send(JSON.dump(this_order.service_json))
            ws.close
          end
      }
```

This waits for the socket to open, then send the message and closes. No need to stop the EventMachine i guess.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this may be it will help you ..**

[How can I push to Faye Server from Rails Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567167/how-can-i-push-to-faye-server-from-rails-controller/33567635#33567635)

Comment: Thanks i'll try since the solution I found randomly causes infinite loops

Comment: it's more stops on the main thread than infinite loops actually

Answer (score -2):

**Using the WebSocket client**

The client supports both the plain-text ws protocol and the encrypted wss protocol, and has exactly the same interface as a socket you would use in a web browser. On the wire it identifies itself as hybi-13.

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'

EM.run {
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('ws://www.example.com/')

  ws.on :open do |event|
  p [:open]
  ws.send('Hello, world!')
end

ws.on :message do |event|
  p [:message, event.data]
end

ws.on :close do |event|
  p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
  ws = nil
end
}
```

The WebSocket client also lets you inspect the status and headers of the handshake response via its status and headers methods.

To connect via a proxy, set the proxy option to the HTTP origin of the proxy, including any authorization information and custom headers you require:

```
ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('ws://www.example.com/', [], {:proxy => {
         :origin  => 'http://username:password@proxy.example.com',
         :headers => {'User-Agent' => 'ruby'}
        }
    })
```

for more help use this [link](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby)

Comment: Thank you for copying exactly the doc from github, but it doesn't answer my question.